# conditional not working properly

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, browser-detection

I am setting up a simple browser checker that should pop up an alert on the user's browser if the browser is not "supported".

I set a global variable in `application.haml` using a library called `detect.js`:

`:javascript
      var ua = detect.parse(navigator.userAgent);`
and I spit it out in the console to make sure it's catching the correct data and it is:

`console.log(ua.browser.family);`

and in `base.coffee` I set up the conditional:

`if ua.browser.family != 'Chrome' || 'Safari' || 'Firefox' || 'Chrome Canary' 
  alert('Your browser is not supported.')`

Now, the alert will pop up on any browser, even if it is Chrome, Safari, Firefox, or Chrome Canary.

Looking for a second pair of eyes... What am I missing to get this to work properly?

Comment: Nevermind, just noticed it was coffeescript

Comment: Putting in parens throws me an error. doesn't .coffee allow that syntax? I have tried `alert "this browser is unsupported"  if ua.browser.family isnt "Safari" or "Chrome" or "Firefox"`  and that does not work

Comment: It does allow no parens if statements. I didn't see the coffee tag on first glance. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should read `if ua.browser.family != 'Chrome' && ua.browser.family != 'Safari' && ua.browser.family != 'Firefox' && ua.browser.family != 'Chrome Canary'`

Comment: you can't use && it will always be false.. since type would be either one of the

Answer (score 3):

The statement `'Chrome' || 'Safari' || 'Firefox' || 'Chrome Canary'` will always evaluate to `'Chrome', so that's not going to work.  You need to test the full condition for each string:

```
if ua.browser.family != 'Chrome' || ua.browser.family != 'Safari' || ua.browser.family != 'Firefox' || ua.browser.family != 'Chrome Canary'
```

Coffescript has a shorter way to test if an array includes an element though:

```
if ua.browser.family in ['Chrome', 'Safari', 'Firefox', 'Chrome Canary']
```

Comment: thanks! OK, I see. what was wrong. The conditional needs to be && instead of | | for it to work properly, as well as the edits you have made (testing the condition for each string).

Comment: @Dear1ofGdBear you can't use && it will always be false.. since type would be either one of them

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo it seems to be working for me. I tried out a few test cases and its good, but I do see your logic. Interesting

Comment: @Dear1ofGdBear yes man you are right..you are actually checking against the negation..got your point (Y)

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ((ua.browser.family != 'Chrome') || (ua.browser.family !='Safari') 
 || (ua.browser.family !='Firefox') || (ua.browser.family !='Chrome Canary')) 
  alert('Your browser is not supported.')
```

try this one..